# Query about PHP cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I'm new PHP guy and I'm using PHP cookie and I'm facing a problem that the cookie can not be set correctly.
Here is the statement of Set Cookie

> setcookie('cookieusername', $username, 100000);

and the statement of Get Cookie

> $cookieusername = $_COOKIE["cookieusername"];

The problem is, the value of `$_COOKIE["cookieusername"];` is not defined.

I don't know what the problem is. I have tired to set the cookie path to '/' but which was still not work.

Comment: can you write exact script you made and it's not working?

Comment: Are you sure headers are not sent already ? `var_dump(headers_sent())` to check. If not, cookies will be loaded on NEXT page visit (You cannot access a cookie you just set)

Comment: Your expiry time is set in past. `100000` is not for how long it should last, it's UNTIL when it should last, read up at php.net/setcookie

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of:

```
setcookie('cookieusername', $username, 100000);
```

you have to do:

```
setcookie('cookieusername', $username, time() + 100000);
```

The reason is that the third parameter is  the expiry time (as a Unix timestamp (number of seconds since the epoch)), not the time until expiry. And [here's the link of manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: Yes, I have set it as your suggested and this cookie have been displayed in firebug, but once it jumped to other page this cookie disappeared somehow.

Comment: Try setcookie('cookieusername', $username, time() + 100000, '/');, it should enable the cookie on your whole domain.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't put the user name in the cookie at all. I would put a hash in that can be searched for in the database, which will give you your username.