# Not able to set the php cookie correctly

Tags: php, cookies

I am having problem with setting up a php cookie, what am I doing wrong? Below I added 3 examples which I tried. Next to the examples, I also tried to change the time which the cookie is working but is all did not work.

Evert time I get the notworking variable indicating that the cookie is not set, do you know what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Example from:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_http_setcookie

```
$works="It is working!";
$notworking="Not working";
$name=20;
setcookie($name_cookie, $name, time() + 100000, '/');

if (isset($_COOKIE[$name_cookie])){
echo $works;

}
else{
    echo $notworking;
}
```

Example from:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php
And
[Query about PHP cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056722/query-about-php-cookie)

Example 2:

```
$works="It is working!";
$notworking="Not working";
$name=20;
setcookie("name_cookie", "name", time() + 100000, '/');

if (isset($_COOKIE["name_cookie"])){
echo $works;
echo $_COOKIE[$name_cookie];
echo $name_cookie;
}
else{
    echo $notworking;
}
```

Example 3

```
$works="It is working!";
$notworking="Not working";
$name=20;
setcookie("name_cookie", $name, time() + 100000, '/');
if (isset($_COOKIE["name_cookie"])){
echo $works;
}
else{
    echo $notworking;
}
```

Comment: Please check [Accessing $_COOKIE immediately after setcookie()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230133/accessing-cookie-immediately-after-setcookie)

Comment: Have you enabled cookie at your browser ??

Comment: In first example, where did you set $name_cookie variable. Please enable error_reporting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you set a cookie, it becomes available in next page load, You can't access it right after creating it.

Comment: Thanks, I checked this and you are right. Thanks voor your helpt

Answer (score 0):

You're setting it correctly.

This is the expected behavior. Cookie is set on server and sent to the client. After the next page refresh, the cookie data is available through `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: Thanks, I checked this and you are right. Thanks voor your helpt